# How does one express "to control" in Esperanto?

Tags: word-choice

I've learned that "kontroli" is a false friend. Using which other word(s) may I express "to control" in Esperanto?

Comment: JC Wells says _kontroli_ is to check/audit/supervise, so a different sense of _to control_. So technically not a false friend, but an ambiguity of the English word, which is translated as different words in Eo.

Answer (score 10):

The closest verb for *to control* is probably *regi*. In some contexts, you might also use *stiri*, *konduki*, etc.

Comment: Which are these contexts? Could you give me some examples?